# Microservices service registry registration and discovery

Tags: web-services, rest, service, amqp, microservices

**Little domain presentation**

I m actually having two microservices :

- User - managing CRUD on users
- Billings - managing CRUD on billings, with a "reference" on a user concerned by the billing

**Explanation**

I need, when a billing is called in a HTTP request, to send the fully billing object with the user loaded. In that case, and in this specifical case, I really need this.

In a first time, I looked around, and it seems that it was a good idea to use message queuing, for asynchronicity, and so the billing service can send on a queue :

> "who's the user with the id 123456 ? I need to load it"

So my two services could exchange, without really knowing each other, or without knowing the "location" of each other.

**Problems**

- My first question is, what is the aim of using a service registry in that case ? The message queuing is able to give us the information without knowing anything at all concerning the user service location no ?
- When do we need to use a service registration :
  In the case of Aggregator Pattern, with RESTFul API, we can navigate through hateoas links. In the case of Proxy pattern maybe ? When the microservices are interfaced by another service ?
- Admitting now, that we use proxy pattern, with a "frontal service". In this case, it's okay for me to use a service registration. But it means that the front send service know the name of the userService and the billing service in the service registration ? Example :

> Service User registers as "UserServiceOfHell:http://80.80.80.80/v1/"
>   on ZooKeeper
>
> Service Billing registers as "BillingService:http://90.90.90.90/v4.3/"

The front end service  needs to send some requests to the user and billing service, it implies that it needs to know that the user service is "UserServiceOfHell". Is this defined at the beginning of the project ?

- Last question, can we use multiple microservices patterns in one microservices architecture or is this a bad practice ?

*NB : Everything I ask is based on http://blog.arungupta.me/microservice-design-patterns/*

Answer (score 5):

A lot of good questions!

First of all, I want to answer your last question - multiple patterns are ok when you know what you're doing. It's fine to mix asynchronous queues, HTTP calls and even binary RPC - it depends on consistency, availability and performance requirements. Sometimes you can see a good fit for simple PubSub and sometimes you need to have distributed lock - microservices are different.

Your example is simple: two microservices need to exchange some information. You chose asynchronous queue - fine, in this case they don't really need to know about each other. Queues don't expect any discovery between consumers.

But we need service discovery in other cases! For example, backing services: databases, caches and *actually queues as well*. Without service discovery you probably hardcoded the URL to your queue, but if it goes down you have nothing. You need to have high availability - cluster of nodes replicating your queue, for example. When you add a new node or existing node crashed - you should not change anything, service discovery tool should understand that and update the registry.

[Consul](https://www.consul.io/) is a perfect modern service discovery tool, you can just use custom DNS name for accessing your backing services and Consul will perform constant health checks and keep your cluster healthy.

The same rule can be applied to microservices - when you have a cluster running service A and you need to access it from service B without any queues (for example, for HTTP call) you have to use service discovery to be sure that endpoint you use will bring you to the healthy node. So it's a perfect fit for Aggregator or Proxy patterns from the article you mentioned.

Probably the most confusion is caused by the fact that you see "hardcoded" URLs in Zookeeper. And you think that you need to manage that manually. Modern tools like Consul or etcd allows you to avoid that headache and just rely on them. It's actually also achievable with Zookeeper, but it'll require more time and resources to have similar setup.

PS: please remember about the most important rule in microservices - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html